# Error when install pods

Tags: ios, rubygems, cocoapods

The following error was obtained when installing pods

```
/Users/mosab/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.30.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:12: undefined method `enforce_available_locales=' for I18n:Module (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/mosab/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.30.0/bin/pod:32
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/pod:23
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try "sudo gem update i18n" in your command line.  Then re-run your pod command.

This fixed it for me.

Comment: This did not solve the same issue on my machine, now I get `cannot load such file -- cocoapods-core`. But a `sudo gem update cocoapods-core` did wonders.